# PHP setlocale() not working for ctype_alpha check

Tags: php, ubuntu, character-encoding, locale

I run this php code:

```
echo "<br>system locales: ".system('locale -a')."<br><br>";
echo "current locales: ".setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)."<br><br>";
var_dump(setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8'));
echo "current locales: ".setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)."<br><br>";
echo "accepting german characters?: ".ctype_alpha("äüöß")."<br><br>";
echo "accepting characters in general?: ".ctype_alpha("test")."<br><br>";
echo "rejecting numbers?: ".ctype_alpha("tes2t")."<br><br>";
```

and get this output:

```
C C.UTF-8 POSIX de_DE.utf8
system locales: de_DE.utf8

current locales: C

string(10) "de_DE.utf8" current locales: de_DE.utf8

accepting german characters?:

accepting characters in general?: 1

rejecting numbers?
```

I expected that after the call to setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8') ctype_alpha would accept german characters like äöüß, as written in the documentation: ["Returns TRUE if every character in text is a letter from the **current locale**, FALSE otherwise."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) but it doesn't. 
What am i doing wrong here?

PHP Version  is : 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8

Comment: What encoding is the `äüöß` string in? In other words, what encoding is the source code file saved as?

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented but, since you are using `utf8` version of the locale, if your file encoding is also UTF-8 you'll have to use `utf8_decode()` to make it work:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');
// Assuming your file encoding is also UTF-8
var_dump(ctype_alpha(utf8_decode('äüöß'))); // bool(true)
// Assuming your file encoding is anything else
var_dump(ctype_alpha('äüöß')); // bool(true)
```

Tested with PHP 5.4.17-cli on a OS X Mavericks machine with UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, KOI8-U and Windows 1252 file encodings.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but:
echo "accepting utf8 decoded german characters?: ".ctype_alpha(utf8_decode('äüöß'))."<br><br>";

returns "accepting utf8 decoded german characters?: " :-(

Comment: If anything, `utf8_encode` is what you want here. But you probably just want to save your source code in the right encoding (UTF-8).

Comment: @Samy I've tried with other file encodings and updated my answer accordingly for what have worked for me.

Comment: Dear downvoter: first try it yourself, latter downvote. What's your argument? Have you ever tried my answer with same conditions? If not, why you downvoted? Why can't you answer the question yourself? :)

Comment: @PauloFreitas I upvoted your answer because i think it is relevant for people not working on an utf8 environment.

Comment: @deceze utf8_encode is also not working, the strings in the real application are not hardcoded but send from an form that is set with accept-charset='UTF-8'.
ctype_alpha is just not working for me thats why I m now using this regex which i found online in the kohana framework: preg_match('/^\pL++$/uD', $str)