# php ctype_alpha with setlocale

Tags: php, setlocale

I'm using `ctype_alpha` to check if name is entered correctly. This is the code:

Get `$ime`:

```
$ime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ime"]);
```

Check `$ime`:

```
if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(
    "'",
    "-",
), "", $ime))) {
    header("Location: error.php?error=14");
    break;
}
```

I'm from Croatia, and we have characters like: `"č", "ć", "š", ...`
So i tried to add setlocale function:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'hr_HR','hrv_HRV', 'hr', 'hrv', 'croatian', 'hrvatski', 'Croatian', 'Hrvatski', 'hr_HR.utf8');
```

But still after using characters `"č", "ć", "š"` it throws me an error (redirect to `error.php?error=14`)

Is there any other way to solve this, because I really need to be able to use those characters?

Comment: [Try `utf8_decode` if your source is also UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929965/php-setlocale-not-working-for-ctype-alpha-check), otherwise you might try a regular expression.

Comment: I tried that already but still getting an error

Comment: Check the return value of `setlocale` (it should be the selected locale, or false if none was found [according to the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)). Note also the warnings about locale selections not being thread-safe (may or not be important on your setup).